# Responsive design with angular material + bootstrap (either one or both?)

Tags: angular, responsive-design, components, bootstrap-5

I am having difficulties with angular material. As far as I can see, there is no easy straight forward way of making a responsive layout with it. However, I am missing really powerful and well integrated components in bootstrap. For instance, reactive table (sorting, filtering, pagination, row selection, etc.). I have seen some suggestions of using those together. I was wondering if I am missing something. For simplicity, I am rather ready to ditch bootstrap if I can make responsive layouts with Angular material easily. Otherwise, I have been thinking of using bootstrap for layouts only. But I am afraid of having issues with CSS collisions. I was wondering, what is a common strategy, are there better/easier alternatives or am I missing something about angular material regarding responsive layout design?

Comment: This needs more focus. What is the exact issue you're facing? Prepare some [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your exact issue. A general "what is a common strategy" falls under a category of questions that are very [subjective](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), since different people will have different "common" strategies.

Comment: You can try using ng-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap or [this library](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap) ([simple table](https://bootstrap.mintplayer.com/basic/table) - [datatable](https://bootstrap.mintplayer.com/advanced/datatables))

Comment: I don't want to introduce bunch of libraries as dependencies. If there is already a datatable in a major library, I rather use that, which may be helpful for other requirements as well.